# CSS Transitions and transforms on SVG elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I am currently trying to rotate an SVG group using a CSS transform and animate it using CSS transitions. I am getting the desired transform but not the animate, any idea on what the issue might be?

Inline SVG Code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hub-icon-container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="70px" height="70px" viewBox="0 0 70 70" enable-background="new 0 0 70 70" xml:space="preserve">
        <g class="hub-icon">
            <path fill="#9B59B6" d="M64.142 23.032L35.001 34.998l14.533 6.271 18.908-7.766c0.689-0.285 1.026-1.087 0.744-1.782l-3.265-7.946C65.635 23.079 64.835 22.747 64.142 23.032z"/>
            <path fill="#F74ED7" d="M64.068 47.142L35.001 34.998l5.845 14.712 18.861 7.876c0.688 0.29 1.495-0.04 1.783-0.73l3.312-7.931C65.09 48.233 64.763 47.431 64.068 47.142z"/>
            <path fill="#F2C40D" d="M46.97 64.138l-11.97-29.14 -6.268 14.534L36.5 68.44c0.284 0.689 1.084 1.026 1.779 0.743l7.946-3.265C46.919 65.634 47.256 64.833 46.97 64.138z"/>
            <path fill="#E67E22" d="M22.863 64.069l12.138-29.071 -14.707 5.846 -7.877 18.859c-0.292 0.692 0.039 1.497 0.731 1.784l7.93 3.311C21.771 65.089 22.573 64.76 22.863 64.069z"/>
            <path fill="#E74C3C" d="M5.865 46.966l29.136-11.968 -14.531-6.267L1.562 36.498c-0.693 0.285-1.028 1.089-0.741 1.78l3.263 7.947C4.369 46.919 5.168 47.254 5.865 46.966z"/>
            <path fill="#19BC9C" d="M5.935 22.858l29.065 12.14 -5.839-14.707 -18.863-7.876c-0.693-0.29-1.495 0.039-1.785 0.73l-3.311 7.931C4.914 21.768 5.241 22.57 5.935 22.858z"/>
            <path fill="#2ECC71" d="M23.032 5.862l11.969 29.136 6.269-14.528L33.506 1.563c-0.286-0.697-1.089-1.03-1.783-0.746l-7.944 3.268C23.084 4.366 22.75 5.168 23.032 5.862z"/>
            <path fill="#3398DB" d="M47.142 5.934L35.001 34.998l14.707-5.841L57.589 10.3c0.286-0.697-0.044-1.499-0.735-1.789l-7.929-3.308C48.232 4.911 47.432 5.245 47.142 5.934z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Compass SCSS

```
.hub-icon-container { 
  @include transition(all 0.5s ease-in-out);
  &:hover {
    .hub-icon {
      transform:rotate(180deg);
      transform-origin:50% 50%;
      -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
      -ms-transform-origin:50% 50%;
      -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
      -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

Compiled CSS

```
.hub-icon-container {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.hub-icon-container:hover .hub-icon {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
}
```

CodePen Link below

http://codepen.io/alexbaulch/pen/bDkhv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it!

The transition was in the wrong place, I had assumed that the transition would descend down to the children elements but apparently not. Also fixed the rotation by animating between 0 and 180 degrees.

Inline SVG

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hub-icon-container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="70px" height="70px" viewBox="0 0 70 70" enable-background="new 0 0 70 70" xml:space="preserve">
        <g class="hub-icon">
            <path fill="#9B59B6" d="M64.142 23.032L35.001 34.998l14.533 6.271 18.908-7.766c0.689-0.285 1.026-1.087 0.744-1.782l-3.265-7.946C65.635 23.079 64.835 22.747 64.142 23.032z"/>
            <path fill="#F74ED7" d="M64.068 47.142L35.001 34.998l5.845 14.712 18.861 7.876c0.688 0.29 1.495-0.04 1.783-0.73l3.312-7.931C65.09 48.233 64.763 47.431 64.068 47.142z"/>
            <path fill="#F2C40D" d="M46.97 64.138l-11.97-29.14 -6.268 14.534L36.5 68.44c0.284 0.689 1.084 1.026 1.779 0.743l7.946-3.265C46.919 65.634 47.256 64.833 46.97 64.138z"/>
            <path fill="#E67E22" d="M22.863 64.069l12.138-29.071 -14.707 5.846 -7.877 18.859c-0.292 0.692 0.039 1.497 0.731 1.784l7.93 3.311C21.771 65.089 22.573 64.76 22.863 64.069z"/>
            <path fill="#E74C3C" d="M5.865 46.966l29.136-11.968 -14.531-6.267L1.562 36.498c-0.693 0.285-1.028 1.089-0.741 1.78l3.263 7.947C4.369 46.919 5.168 47.254 5.865 46.966z"/>
            <path fill="#19BC9C" d="M5.935 22.858l29.065 12.14 -5.839-14.707 -18.863-7.876c-0.693-0.29-1.495 0.039-1.785 0.73l-3.311 7.931C4.914 21.768 5.241 22.57 5.935 22.858z"/>
            <path fill="#2ECC71" d="M23.032 5.862l11.969 29.136 6.269-14.528L33.506 1.563c-0.286-0.697-1.089-1.03-1.783-0.746l-7.944 3.268C23.084 4.366 22.75 5.168 23.032 5.862z"/>
            <path fill="#3398DB" d="M47.142 5.934L35.001 34.998l14.707-5.841L57.589 10.3c0.286-0.697-0.044-1.499-0.735-1.789l-7.929-3.308C48.232 4.911 47.432 5.245 47.142 5.934z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Compass SCSS

```
.hub-icon-container {
    &:hover {
        .hub-icon {
            transform:rotate(180deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
            -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
        }
    }
    .hub-icon {
        @include transition(all 0.5s ease-in-out);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform-origin:50% 50%;
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform-origin:50% 50%;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    }
}
```

Compiled CSS

```
.hub-icon-container:hover .hub-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.hub-icon-container .hub-icon {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

CodePen Updated below

http://codepen.io/alexbaulch/pen/bDkhv